# Cannot open RPM, skipping in Dockerfile

Tags: docker

I'm trying to create a Dockerfile to build our reusable image.  What I have so far is

```
FROM crystaltwix/centos-mono
MAINTAINER crystaltwix

ADD ./rpms/MyRpm.rpm ./rpms
RUN yum --nogpgcheck localinstall ./rpms/MyRpm.rpm
```

I get an error that says

```
Cannot open: ./rpms/Myrpm.rpm.  Skipping.
```

What I don't understand why it doesn't work is, if I do run the image in my container:

```
sudo docker run -i -t -v /home/crystaltwix/projects/rpms:/opt/rpms crystaltwix/centos-mono /bin/bash
```

Then in the shell of my container, I do the same command:

```
yum --nogpgcheck localinstall ./rpms/MyRpm.rpm
```

This works fine.  It just doesn't work within my Dockerfile.  Am I missing something specific about the way Dockerfile builds images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#add:

`If <src> is any other kind of file, it is copied individually along with its metadata. In this case, if <dest> ends with a trailing slash /, it will be considered a directory and the contents of <src> will be written at <dest>/base(<src>).`

`ADD ./rpms/MyRpm.rpm ./rpms` results in ./rpms being the MyRpm.rpm file.  Try `ADD ./rpms/MyRpm.rpm ./rpms/` instead.